# Are cookies files?

Tags: cookies

Yesterday I was asked to add the following statement to a website:

> Cookies are small text files which are placed on your computer and
>   remember your preferences/ some details of your visit.

I pushed it back to the editors saying that cookies are not files, but data stored into a file.

They said that the text was based on the BBC cookie's policy page. So I read other pages about it:
https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170514

Wiki says something different (which is what I thought was right):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Anyone with enough knowledge about the subject to help?

Comment: As wiki says *... is a small piece of data* - how the browser/user-agent chooses to store this (a file, a database record) is somewhat irrelevant so long as the underlying system works according to the specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, regardless of Twitter or BBC's cookie policy, let's look at [Wikipedia's definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie):

> A cookie, also known as an HTTP cookie, web cookie, or browser cookie, is a small piece of data sent from a website and stored in a user's web browser while the user is browsing that website.

We may indeed just be arguing semantics here, but I think your version is more accurate than the editors' at least in terms of the abstraction being discussed.  I'd slightly modify it:

> Cookies are not files, but data.  Data which may be stored in a file, but data nonetheless.

Now it's entirely possible that *every* web browser happens to store this data in files.  I can't say that with any certainty, but it's possible.  The browser isn't *required* to store it in a file, text or otherwise.  It's just required to store the data.

Now, having said that, if this is the language that the customer wants to use on the customer's website, then it's their choice.  You are fee to advise them (even, I'd argue, expected to advise them as a professional) but ultimately we're just talking about text copy on a webpage, which the customer defines.

To put it another way... Their policy may be inaccurately worded, but it's their policy.  Changing policy is a business decision.  From a business perspective it's likely more important that the company's website accurately reflect the company's policy than that it accurately reflect an industry technical definition.

Comment: Thanks. I needed confirmation from someone else. You would expect Twitter people to know what they are talking about...